# It was a come-from-behind victory?

Tags: phrases

Biology used to be my least favorite subject in the field of science, but it became my favorite science subject. It was from my great effort and work to understand biology, so i could say it became my favorite subject because it was my least favorite subject.

Could I say that this was a come-from-behind victory?

Should I use a quotation around "come-from-behind victory" because it's a metaphor?

Comment: What is the antecedent of "it" in "*It* was from my great effort..."?

Comment: I don't think "come-from-behind victory" really makes sense here, because you were never *behind* anything.  "come-from-behind victory" implies that you were lagging behind some competitor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like using the word "victory" because the branches of science aren't really competing with one another. I think it's usable, but it seems like an awkward fit.

Another phrase you could use instead is ***latecomer to the dance***. That phrase is used when someone or something gets started later than the others, but still ends up in a shining or prominent position. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latecomer) defines *latecomer* as:

> someone or something that has recently arrived or become involved in something

As an example usage, a [2006 report on auto manufacturing](http://asq.org/quality-report/reports/20060815.html) compares Hyundai with companies like Honda and Toyota, and reads:

> Hyundai, the latecomer to the dance, single-mindedly pursued quality by copying the Japanese quality model.

So, you could say something like this:

> Insofar as my love of the sciences goes, biology was a latecomer to the dance.

Answer (score 0):

For me to do so well in biology, my least favorite subject in the past, was a come-from-behind victory as **I was really at the bottom of the class** and had to work very hard to understand it.

It can only be a victory, if you conquered something, or overcame something, or had been losing at something before starting to win. No quotation marks are needed. Metaphors don't require quotation marks; they just need to used properly.

So, come-from-behind victory is fine as it was  your personal victory in a subject in which you did not excel.